# How can I filter Bing Location API results by user location for auto complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, bing-api, bing-maps

I have this function to return bing address suggestions based off a user entered address. **I'm already specifying userLocation**, but the results are not nearly as accurate as I would imagine they should be. Is there anything extra I should be doing here? I can manually specify the state or postal code if I have to, but I'd rather avoid doing post processing.

For example, typing 111 returns results from 111, NY, 111 Sweden, 111 Denmark. I would like to restrict this to only the US at least, and really only within a few states which I can hardcode. When I manually specify the options for postalCode in the data, it overrides what I've used in query.

```
    var geolocate = function(options) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            key: "KEY",
            q: options.address,
            userLocation: options.latitude + ',' + options.longitude,
            maxResults: options.maxResults,
        },
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            if (options.success instanceof Function) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, text) {
            alert('ERROR:\n');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this will actually do what I intended (Unless testing proves otherwise) I was specifying the address as a single param, q, but if I specify addressLine in combination with userLocation, it filters the results as expected.

```
var geolocate = function(options) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            key: "KEY",
            addressLine: options.address,
            countryRegion: 'US',
            userLocation: options.latitude + ',' + options.longitude,
            maxResults: options.maxResults,
        },
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            if (options.success instanceof Function) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, text) {
            alert('ERROR:\n\n');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the Bing Maps API beyond some tinkering I did a while ago... but have you tried passing the ip or including locality? You may need to reverse lookup the users Lat/Lng to get a city name... why they wouldn't extrapolate that info from userLocation is beyond me though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

Comment: I have unfortunately, both IP and userLocation don't seem to narrow the results down very drastically. I need to exclude results all together, especially those out of US.